# Java Random Number with seed changes after a day

Tags: java, random, random-seed

I was using the code below to generate random number with seed so that I can generate back the same results next time.

```
int seed = 100;    
Random rand = new Random(seed);
```

I manage to get back the same results from the program on the same day, but after a day or two i get a completely different results. Is there a problem of the way I implement the random seed? Anyone encounter this before?

Comment: Assuming that you use `java.util.Random`, what you describe is not possible - for a given seed (100 in your example), `new Random(seed).nextXxx()` will always return the same numbers, in the same order... You may have changed the seed or the code that generates the sequence.

Comment: This must be observational error. `Random`s with the same seed produce the same sequence of numbers; see [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). It's deterministic. You actually have to go to great lengths to get non-deterministic randomness from a computer. (Edit: Actually, you can't get it *from the computer*; the examples I was thinking of are actually just randomness being fed into the computer from an external source and then modified afterward, to wit, brownian detectors, etc.)

Comment: Search for `new Random()` - somewhere there is a fould egg.  The most likely is that the algorithm changed, An extra `random.nextInt(13);` Especially changing `nextInt(12)` to `nextInt(13)` already changes the subsequent numbers if I remember correctly.

Comment: You always get the same result regardless of when you call it.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey. I think you didnt read my question properly. Im trying to get back the same sequence of number but it gives me another sequence of number the next day

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. I tried a few times on it. The same day u will get the same results but if u try running it again it will be different. Did you try? give it a try first. And this shouldnt be off topic since random number is 1 of the usually things that we use.

Comment: @kojh and I can tell you that you diagnosis is not correct as it's not possible. The code is very simple, has not changed in more than a decade and doesn't do this. There is no call in the code to get the time. If this is happening there is a bug in your JVM and I would use one which works.

Comment: @kojh the bug would need to be fundemental in how it performs calculations. Thos could happen if there is a bug in the JIT optimiser but this is very rare especially for such a widely used class.

Comment: @kojh: Again: `Random` doesn't do what you're describing. The question is therefore off-topic: It's asking about something that doesn't happen. I just ran this locally and also on [ideone](http://ideone.com/zu7Uk2). It returned the expected results. It will also return the expected results tomorrow. And next week. Etc. Let go of the idea it's doing what we're telling you for certain it isn't doing, so you can be open to what is *actually* happening and therefore fix it.

Comment: @kojh: Ran it again today. Guess what? No change, exact same sequence returned. Having got that result locally, I forked the IDEOne above and [made a new one](http://ideone.com/iBbKKJ) to get a fresh run on their hardware. Same result: The same sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Citing from [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers.

It really depends on how you use that instance. It has to be strictly the same sequence of methods you call.

This means the problem is in the code that calls the methods on your `Random` instance. The sequence of the methods called seems to depend on some conditional that can change it.